# Netflix TV show or miniseries involving portals

Tags: story-identification, tv

This has been bugging me for a while, but I distinctly remember the existence of a show I watched on Netflix when I was a lot younger. Before 2015 at least. I only remember a few random things that could be wrong.

It involved portals of some kind. There was one female character that I couldn’t tell whether she was “good or bad”. I think the main twist was that a skeleton with a bag found at the beginning of the series turned out to be one of the main characters who got stuck in a desert-like place. May have involved time travel. I think there were dinosaurs.

Sorry, but I was young so I don’t remember much. I also remember a motel for some reason. Please help if you can, thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Bits of the description match up with the Stargate: Atlantis episode Epiphany; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Fgs6Rp4DiY. John gets stuck behind a time-dilating portal. You don't see his skeleton, but you do see his bag and there was a dinosaur-like monster. No motel, but they did feature in other SG and SGA episodes

Comment: RE: "*..when I was a lot younger. Before 2015 at least.*"  Wow, now I feel really old.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pretty confident that this is [Primeval](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primeval_(TV_series)). Ran for five seasons plus a spin-off, starting in 2007. @user888379 confirmed in the comments that Netflix ran the series in around the right timeframe.

The basic premise is that a series of 'anomalies' - portals to other times - start to open. A British team is formed to investigate them, and to try to stop dinosaurs and future predators invading modern times.

The ex-wife of the lead character, Helen Cutter, is played as an antagonist, but does throw in some justification for her actions on a wider scale (humanity is destroying the earth, it would be better if we didn't exist) that throws up some ambiguity.

Several episodes involved a desert setting, and time travel was a key feature.

Having looked back at summaries, the scene you describe with the skeleton turning out to be a key character is in the last episode of season 1, closing a mystery set up in the first episode.

Comment: Netflix did show it, in the U.S. at least. That's how I became acquainted with it, and the timeframe from the OP sounds right for when I watched it.

Comment: The show was mostly an excuse to use dinosaur rendering SFX from the Walking With Dinosaurs documentaries, so I’d think dinos or those future predators should have been more apparent to the OP.

Comment: Fair point, although the first season included millipedes and Dodos, so I could see why the dinosaurs might not be a clear memory in vaguely-recalled series.

Comment: I suspect the "motel" was the golf club in S01E05

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I went on Hulu and watched the end of season 1 and this is definitely it. I recognized the setting and character names. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: This show is very high in my estimation of shows with the most quality they don’t deserve. It has no business being good—it was an excuse to re-use existing work in an attempt to have some answer to _Doctor Who_, arguably the most notable member of the cast was a pop star who got an excuse to spend much of her time in her underwear by like episode 2, and yet the entire show is stunningly good.